# Store data and use it in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am right now trying to implement a dislike/like functionality in my android app. I can't figure out how to store all the data I get from users (a like or a dislike) and use that data to show the amount of users that have pressed like/dislike in the app? Does someone have any ideas of how I should do this?

The app is based of many mini-games and when the user has finished a game they can leave a like or dislike on the game, if they press like it should get stored and used to display how many likes/dislikes the game has on the mini-game start screen.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to set your own database in a server with like and dislike count and web services to actually like and dislike as it looks like you want it to be a multi-user app and connected to the internet.

Would appreciate if you added more specifics on how you want to implement it to give you a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Explained it a bit more, don't know if I am being specific enough, if that is the case please tell me!

Comment: I would suggest to develop your own web api connected to a database, so users can send a like or dislike through http, where your web api would receive that like or dislike and add it to a your mini-game in the database, and that way many users can like and dislike and also check the total likes and dislikes of a mini-game.

Comment: So you don't suggest using firestore for this problem?

Comment: You could use Firebase' Firestore, but in that case I would recommend Firebase' Realtime Database!